# What part needs to be replaced when fridge gets too warm or too cold at times?

Tags: refrigerator, freezer

So the freezer seems to work fine, but the fridge will either get too warm or too cold at times. We change the setting so it'll be warmer or colder, but it doesn't settle to the right level. It can get cold enough since stuff on the bottom of the fridge will freeze. I'm guessing it's a thermostat that isn't working correctly, or whatever reads it. Any ideas on which parts to replace?

It's a Whirlpool model eb9fvbxwq01, with the freezer on the bottom.

Comment: Are you sure your door seals are good? They could be letting heat in.

Comment: Also, the precise model number of the Whirlpool fridge may help, so the controls can be determined.

Comment: eb9fvbxwq01 is the model #

Comment: I think the door seals are ok

Comment: Might be worth a good defrost. Iced up fans or air ducts between the fridge and freezer can cause problems with air distribution between the two. Mind you, it's mostly just 70+ years of a poor control interface being perpetuated in fridge/freezers as opposed to 2 thermostats.

Comment: @user14094230 please [edit] your question to put vital info (like model numbers) where people are most likely to find it. Also, you should know that comments can get deleted, losing that info for ever.

Comment: Is this like a daily occurrence, where it's cold at 8am and warmer at noon, and colder at 4pm, or is it a seasonal occurrence?

Comment: It's been over some days it seems. Maybe just the vent in the freezer was blocked.

Answer (score 2):

All the refrigerators I have seen have only one refrigeration unit and thermostat driving the freezer, with an adjustable air vent to control how much freezer cold gets to the fridge part.

Your description sounds like the freezer is too cold, and the fridge cannot either stay warm enough to keep its food from freezing, or you restrict the cold air flow from the freezer enough to not let the fridge cool down enough. Setting those controls is a balancing act.

Since your freezer is working fine, there should be no parts to replace. Use a thermometer inside the freezer to determine if your freezer is set too cold. Adjust the freezer thermostat control until you get the correct feezer temperatures. Then move the thermometer to the fridge part and adjust the fridge control until you get good fridge temperatures.

Note that cold drops, so food at the bottom of the fridge part will be cooler than food at the top part.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and had to replace the damper door control assembly.  Basically it's a vent that opens/closes based on the temp within the refrigerator section, letting air in from the freezer.

For example:
https://www.partselect.ca/PS11750106-Whirlpool-WPW10196393-Damper-Control-Assembly.htm?SourceCode=20&SearchTerm=EB9FVBXWQ01&ModelNum=EB9FVBXWQ01&ModelID=1619382